# Как сделать всплывающую подсказку только для 1-ого столбца JTable?

Tags: jtable, java, swing

Нужно, что бы при наведении курсора на определенный столбец вылезала всплывающая подсказка с содержимым этого столбца.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо определить заголовок таблицы, в котором указать tooltip для каждой из колонок. Пример [здесь](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/JTablewithTooltip.htm)